# Expandable menu (with submenus) and unique highlighted selection of list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a menu that contains a variety of sub lists (up to three levels). The idea is the user should be able to expand and contract all of the options at any time, **but only be able to select at most one bottom level list element (across all the lists and sub lists contained within the structure)**. here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// On page load, reset display style of ul's to 'none'
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init1);
function init1() {
    $('#Ul1').css({ "display": "none" });
    $('#Ul2').css({ "display": "none" });
    $('#Ul3').css({ "display": "none" });
};
// Function that expands and collapses ul when it is clicked
function ExpCol1(arg1) {
    if ($('#' + arg1).css("display") == "none") {
        $('#' + arg1).css({ "display": "block" });
    } else {
        $('#' + arg1).css({ "display": "none" });
    };
};
// My attempt at forcing the clicked on li elements underneath the container1 div to change colour when clicked on
$('#container1 li').click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFF00");
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="container1" class="col-sm-6">
    <li onclick="ExpCol1('Ul1')" class="list-group-item"><span>Option1</span>
        <ul id="Ul1" class="list-group">
        <br />
            <li class="list-group-item">Option1.1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option1.2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option1.3</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option1.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="ExpCol1('Ul2')" class="list-group-item"><span>Option2</span>
        <ul id="Ul2" class="list-group">
        <br />
            <li class="list-group-item">Option2.1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option2.2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option2.3</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option2.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="ExpCol1('Ul3')" class="list-group-item"><span>Option3</span>
        <ul id="Ul3" class="list-group">
        <br />
            <li class="list-group-item">Option3.1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option3.2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option3.3</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Option3.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to build it so that when the user selects a list element, the element is highlighted (and I can transfer its ID to a separate process later on when the user clicks a 'submit' button).

The problem i'm having is that I can't work out how to keep the selected options highlighted. The display style keeps reverting back to 'none' whenever the list elements are clicked for some reason. I'm also wondering if there is a better way to implement this kind of expandable drill down menu using (or not using?) the bootstrap framework (a bit like drilling down into folders in windows explorer to select files). I couldn't find any useful documentation online about how to do it (not even sure if this kind of menu has a specific name that I should be googling instead!). Has anyone ever created anything similar before? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery is a mess :)
Try this self explained code :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
      $('#Ul1, #Ul2, #Ul3').hide(); // HIDE THE UL(s)
      $('#container1 > li').on('click', function() { // ON PARENT LI CLICK
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); // ADD A CLASS SELECTED
TO THE CLICKED LI AND REMOVE THIS CLASS FROM OTHER PARENT LI
        $('.selected').children('ul').toggle(); // SHOW THE CHILDREN OF SELECTED
OR HIDE THEM BACK
        $('.selected').siblings().children('ul').hide(); // HIDE THE UL CHILDREN OF THE OTHER PARENT LI (IN CASE ANOTHER PARENT LI IS CLICKED WHILE ONE HAS HIS CHILDREN OPENED) 
        $('.selected').children('span').css("background-color", "#FFFF00"); // THE SAN OF SELECTED HAS A YELLOW COLOR
        $('.selected').siblings().children('span').css("background-color", ""); // THE SPAN OF THE SIBLIGNS OF SELECTED ARE/REMAINS WHITE
      });
    });
```

---

Of course, there are many ways to accomplish it, I'm just showing you the logic.
Hope this helps, SYA ;)
And this is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qtn0sx9/) ;)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! And thanks for the cleaning up tips! :)