# Expand/Collapse element (div) on click to display hidden content without setting an 'id' using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

New member so apologies for question format in advance.

Expand/Collapse element (div) on click to display hidden content without setting an 'id' using css and jquery so element stays expanded until selected again whilst also adjusting css on mouseover andselected states.

Have spent days researching and found button class solution but editing this in dreamwaever won't work due to button display.

Initial div container set at 600px then when mouseover/select adjust width to 620px (makes it pop out on screen a bit) color and background color. On select div to stay in selected state whilst now displaying hidden div content. Collapse/hide on next select.

In particular without setting an 'id' for any element.

My crude example here: http://www.calibregroup.us/jquery/jquery18.php

Have tried to put code here but the system won't accept my format.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you're not going to be able to do so without adding an id (**Unless**, you only have one div on your website [which is doubtful]). Your best bet is to set an id on the element, whether it just be "expand_collapse" or something else. You can set the css properties using jQuery as well, and I'm assuming you know how to do so.

Friendly reminder that you can use a website such as [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [repl.it](https://repl.it/) to create a shareable thing of code, and it will run as long as you use the jQuery CDN in the HTML header.

Comment: an id for the div if a single name as you suggest is fine I just didn't want to give each div a unique id. New to jquery (actually everything) so don't know how to set css properties in jquery. If there is a post with such an example for expand_collapse of a div can you send a link. When I've searched most answers are 3+ years old.

Thanks for the reminder, I'll take a look.

Comment: If each div is taking the same animation, then only one id will be needed for each one. If you'd like to learn jQuery in a few days, take a look at the Codecademy course (https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery). I learned it in just a few days, actually just recently. They made it easy to understand, and it was easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can **absolutely** do it without ID !
Your script uses class name
`var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("expandme");`
`var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");`
and not ID
I've recently replied to a similar question, [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867708/expandable-menu-with-submenus-and-unique-highlighted-selection-of-list-element/43873857#43873857)
and made a simple demonstration with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qtn0sx9/).
Just change your ID(s) by classes !
The fiddle is just an approach, an explanation of the process, there are many ways to do it.

**EDIT**
I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fs2x46e/) for you
As you can see:
1- On the click event of `.expandme`
2- We grab his parent `.container` and goes down to the children of `.container` (it's children `div`) but not the `.expandme` and we toggle their visibility.
3- We grab again his parent and goes to it's siblings (just the other `.container`) and goes to it's children but not the `.expandme` and hide them. We do this to hide it if it's open and the other `.expandme` is clicked !

```
$('.expandme').click( function() {
$(this).parent().children('div:not(.expandme)').toggle();
$(this).parent().siblings('.container').children('div:not(.expandme)').hide();
});
```

Hope this helps :)
SYA

Comment: had a look but as not a developer just went round in curcles. Your example relates to a list and I'm trying div's. I've put in a fiddle as best I can. Seem to lose the effect when moving the mouse away. Outer box changes to brown from grey but should stay grey while expanded. Also lose the space between div's when both are open. Also the increase width in div on mouseover is lost again once mouse moved even though element is selected. Sure there's a neater solution but beyond my scope without help.

https://jsfiddle.net/calibregroup/r5hhujma/2/

Comment: @guvna I've edited my answear with a fiddle and an explanation. ALSO, your html has one extra div that I removed. Hope this will help you. SYA :)

Comment: making headway. Removed line of script as want to keep div's open until selected again. Behaviour not working after selecting and mouseaway. Div won't stay in state set by css. Created a fiddle but (https://jsfiddle.net/calibregroup/Lvrc5qh1/) but couldn't get it to wrok so published here for review/comments (http://www.calibregroup.us/jquery/jquery21.php). Would be useful maybe to learn how to adjust css from within the script. Unfortuneatly I have to work so no more time on this today!

Comment: Hello, I've just updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lvrc5qh1/5/ you did'nt set javascript to use jQuery that's all :) Your fiddle is working fine :) SYA :)

Comment: Cheers, have spent hours learning jQuery. All ok on examples with one div or element but as soon as I need 3 (like my example) I can only get so far. Using .click .toggleClass and .hoover. Not going to spend more time on this but I have two last questions:
1) Is there an obvious reason my div won't stay expanded to 630px when selected?
2) Why is the margin between the div.container lost when selected?

Comment: Actually I have a 3rd question but probably same reason as 1 & 2.
3) Why doesn't div.container outline stay #999 after selection and mouse away?

Comment: this was my jquery attempt so far https://jsfiddle.net/t2k56jjo/ but you can see it's left wanting as div.son remains open on click. I tried manipulating css eg $(this).css("background-color",'#red'); in a focus but focus doesn't seem to like firefox. In fact is this an underlying problem in that jQuery is not that compatible with firefox (what I use for my intranet)?

Comment: Hello, it's now being unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you could make a 1- 2- 3- ... sept text I'll try to help, I unable to figure out what you are trying to do in your last fiddle. Tell me exactly what should be the expected behaviour. SYA